# Detect border of partially hidden ellipse with known center (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, ellipse

I have to detect the border of ellipses in gray images. These images contains a lot of stuff, but there is always a (partially hidden) ellipse. I know where is the center of this ellipse in the image.

Advantages:

1. Ellipse is always visible
2. Point near the center of the ellipse is known
3. Ellipse is always black (value = [0, 50] on 8bits)

Troubles:

1. White blobs (value = [220, 255]) can appears into the ellipse (not outside)
2. Black artefacts (value = [0, 80]) can hide 0% to 50% of the ellipse and white blobs (but the center is still known)

Here are 4 examples images which represent the different situations that can appear :

[image: Diagrams]

I've tried severals algo (Hough circle, ellipse detection, ..) but none of them managed all the different situations. Moreover, they don't benefit of the known center.
All suggestions are welcome !

Comment: Only 1 ellipse per image? Troubles 1 states that there's no white outside the ellipse... what about the white background in your example images? Some constraints on the execution time?

Comment: Only one "black" ellipse per image. The background is not white and not uniform, it's generally grey [50, 150]. Execution time must be around 1ms if possible. Larger execution time can be admitted, but no more than 3ms

Answer (score 1):

Try RANSAC method, it will allow you avoid noise edges and fit ellipce accurate. Ellipse have 2 focuses, you can find them, knowing your ellipse equation, and then find middle between them. It will be you ellipse center of mass.

Example of code for RANSAC ellipse fitting: https://github.com/seisgo/EllipseFit